# Unicode in PDF Metadata

Tags: pdf, unicode, input-encodings, metadata

There are several ways of setting PDF meta data when compiling LaTeX documents. The two most popular ways are arguably via `pdfinfo`,

```
\pdfinfo{
   /Author (Erwin Schrödinger)
}
```

and `hyperref`,

```
\usepackage[pdftex,
  pdfauthor={Erwin Schrödinger},
]{hyperref}
```

With both methods, however, the above example produces [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) in the PDF output:

[image: evince screenshot]

```
$ pdfinfo main.pdf
Title:          
Subject:        
Keywords:       
Author:         Erwin SchrÃ¶dinger
[...]
```

Adding `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` makes no difference.

How to fix this?

Comment: you need unicode option in hyperref to use utf8 in pdf metadada fields

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `ö` is available in PDFDocEncoding. But LaTeX expands the option before passing it to `hyperref` without giving `hyperref` the chance to setup the macros for the PDF string conversion and changing the font encoding.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Package `hyperref`

`hyperref` encodes correctly, but the options should be set *after* `hyperref` is loaded. Otherwise LaTeX expands the options the hard way and `hyperref` will only see the expanded garbage.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={Erwin Schrödinger},
}
```

Extended example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% utf8, for example
\usepackage[
  pdfencoding=auto,% or unicode
  psdextra,
]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={Erwin Schrödinger},
}
\begin{document}
  \null
\end{document}
```

The meta data strings are encoded in PDFDocEncoding or UTF-16BE with BOM in the PDF file. Full power of Unicode for the meta data and bookmarks are enabled by the following `hyperref` options:

```
\usepackage[
  pdfencoding=auto,% or unicode
  psdextra,
]{hyperref}
```

`pdfencoding=auto` is more flexible than `unicode`. If the string fits the PDFDocEncoding (an 8-bit encoding), then this encoding is used, otherwise Unicode.

## Low level, manually

The low level version for specifying the meta data with pdfTeX and without `hyperref` would look like:

```
\pdfinfo{/Author(Erwin Schr\string\366dinger)}
```

The Unicode variants:

```
\begingroup
  \escapechar=`\\
  \edef\.{\string\000}%
  \pdfinfo{/Author(\string\376\string\377% BOM
    \.E\.r\.w\.i\.n\. \.S\.c\.h\.r\.\string\366\.d\.i\.n\.g\.e\.r)}%
\endgroup
```

or as hexadecimal string:
     \pdfinfo{/Author}

The PDF specification tells, which encoding can be used, PDFDocEncoding is listed as full table in Annex D "Character Sets and Encodings".

## Low level, but with automatic encoding conversions

If you want to convert from UTF-8 (or other input encoding), then package `stringenc` helps
(LaTeX and plain TeX formats):
Plain TeX example:

```
% UTF-8 encoded source file
\input stringenc.sty\relax

\def\MyAuthor{Erwin Schrödinger}
\edef\BOM{\string\376\string\377}
\StringEncodingConvert{\PdfAuthor}{\MyAuthor}{utf8}{utf16be}
\StringEncodingSuccessFailure{}{%
  \errmessage{Conversion from utf8 to utf16be failed for author string}%
}
\pdfinfo{/Author(\BOM\pdfescapestring{\PdfAuthor})}%
\null
\bye
```

A more elaborate example, reimplementing `pdfencoding=auto`:

```
% UTF-8 encoded source file
\input stringenc.sty\relax

\def\GeneratePdfString#1#2{%
  \StringEncodingConvertTest{#1}{#2}{utf8}{pdfdoc}{%
    % Success: \PdfAuthor with PDFDocEncoding
    % Make full PDF string inclusive brackets
    \edef#1{(\pdfescapestring{#1})}%
  }{%
    \StringEncodingConvert{#1}{#2}{utf8}{utf16be}%
    \StringEncodingSuccessFailure{%
      % Success: \PdfAuthor with UTF-16BE
    }{%
      \errmessage{Conversion from utf8 to utf16be failed for author string}%
    }%
    % Make full PDF string with BOM for case UTF-16BE
    \edef#1{(\BOM\pdfescapestring{#1})}%
  }%
}
\edef\BOM{\string\376\string\377}%

% Usage
\def\MyAuthor{Erwin Schrödinger}
\GeneratePdfString\PdfAuthor{\MyAuthor}
\GeneratePdfString\PdfTitle{Unicode string example ☺}

\pdfinfo{%
  /Author\PdfAuthor
  /Title\PdfTitle
}%
\null
\bye
```

The input need not to be encoding in UTF-8, package `stringenc` supports much more encodings.

Comment: `\hypersetup{pdfauthor={Erwin Schrödinger}}` doesn _not_ work for me, `\hypersetup{pdfauthor={Erwin Schr\"odinger}}` does.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer Then you haven't (yet) loaded package `inputenc` with the right option.

Comment: Is there a latex3 way to do the same thing that is proposed with stringenc.sty

Comment: @Callegar When I implemented the package I did not want to limit the usability of the package to a sole TeX format; the package has a topic that is unrelated to a TeX format. Therefore, the package can be used, for example, in LaTeX, plain TeX, even iniTeX ("one package to rule them all").