# silence package leads to an error if the hyperref's pdftitle option contains a blackboard bold math letter

Tags: hyperref, blackboard, amsfonts, silence

If the `hyperref`'s `pdftitle` option contains a blackboard bold math letter,  the `silence` package leads to the error (compilation silently stops after `(./test.out)` and a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is needed):

> ! Interruption.
>   \sl@StoreMessage ...oveGobbletwo #1\sl@Terminator 
>                                                     \@gobbletwo \sl@Terminator...
>   l.11 \hypersetup{pdftitle=$\mathbb{A}$

MCE pointing out the trouble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\hypersetup{pdftitle=$\mathbb{Z}$}
\end{document}
```

Do you know why and how make all of this compatible?

Comment: Why do you try to set the pdftitle to something that doesn't even make it to the PDF?

Comment: The `$\mathbb{Z}$` will not survive all the way through `hyperref`'s cleaning mechanism and only the `Z` will be inserted in the pdf title. If you can change to XeTeX or LuaTeX then you can use just `ℤ`. And apparently the `silence` package leads to an infinite loop, then you need Ctrl+C to exit it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behaviour you see is due to a collection of unfortunate bad interactions between `silence`, `hyperref`, and `\mathbb`.

First, let us know that `\mathbb` is not expandable, so

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\edef\tempa{$\mathbb{Z}$}
\end{document}
```

throws an error. If you add `\usepackage{silence}` or even `\usepackage[safe]{silence}`, it chokes with the code above (I don't think it should, but...). But you are using a primitive `\edef` with a non expandable command, so the outcome is really low level, and I think it's out of the scope of a `silence` package to cope with this.

Yes, but what does `pdftitle` has to do with `\edef`?

`pdftitle` eventually uses `\pdfstringdef` to turn the TeX command into a valid pdf string and issue a warning like

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 5.
```

when an invalid token is found. Somewhere in the way `\pdfstringdef` does something along the lines of

```
\xdef\@pdftitle{#1}
```

where `#1` is the `$\mathbb{Z}$`, and we already saw that this doesn't work even without `hyperref` or `silence`, so we can't expect it to work now.

`hyperref`, however, is clever enough to make unexpandable things expandable handing it to `\xdef`, so if you do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\hypersetup{pdftitle=$\mathbb{Z}$}
\end{document}
```

you get a pdf with title `Z` and two warnings:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 5.

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 5.
```

because of the `$` that are unexpandable as well.

If you try to add `silence` though, it chokes as before leading to the behaviour you found.

If you want to keep this setup, then you can load `silence` with the `safe` option or issue `\SafeMode` before the `\hypersetup`. You can call `\BoldMode` later on to return to normal.

This will, however, result in a pdf titled `mathbb allowed only in math modeZ` and three extra warnings similar to the ones above. `\mathbb` cannnot be used in text mode, and the pdf title is, in essence, text.

#### The actual answer

You can, however, get the `ℤ` in the pdf title without the need to resort to math-mode. [According to out local pdf expert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245969/134574) you can directly use `ℤ` as long as you load `hyperref` with the right options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[
  pdfencoding=auto,% or unicode
  psdextra,
]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\hypersetup{pdftitle=ℤ}
\end{document}
```

or, the obscure way, with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\hypersetup{pdftitle={\376\377\041\044}}
\end{document}
```

with or without the error-obfuscating `silence` package.

Comment: Wow! Very nice. And I incidentally discovered the `hyperref`'s `psdextra` option (which isn't documented AFAICS).

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Indeed, there's no mention of it in the documentation. Basically it loads [psdextra.def](https://www.tug.org/texlive//Contents/live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/psdextra.def) which contains a handful of redefinitions that are executed in `\pdfstringdef`. But I just checked and the answer above apparently works without this option... I don't think it's necessary actually. The definitions in `psdextra.def` are mostly in the form  `\let\<command>\text<command>`...

Comment: @DenisBitouzé it is documented in the hyperref README, I already have [an open ticket](https://github.com/ho-tex/hyperref/issues/69) on the issue that for some reason lots of hyperref is only documented in the readme and not in the manual.

Answer (score 2):

This comes from `\mathbb`  expansion inside famous `\pdfstringdef`.

The following works for me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\@latex@error\@gobbletwo}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\hypersetup{pdftitle=$\mathbb{Z}$}
\end{document}
```

---

The explanation is that `hyperref` does `\let \GenericError \@gobblefour` for `pdfstringdef`. But silence package redefines `\@latex@error`, which originally used this `\GenericError`. Now it doesn't hence the expansion of `\mathbb` (which causes execution of `\@latex@error` because not in math mode) causes havoc.

By doing

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\@latex@error\@gobbletwo}
```

one works around this problem.

Comment: Nice caving expedition! Maybe I should not rely on `silence` package anymore, as it seems to not be maintained.

Comment: `silence` is incompatible with `hyperref` in the sense that `hyperref` takes special measures to control LaTeX errors raised from expanding macros, but `silence` breaks this mechanism. My workaround is a bit brutal, and there might be some better way to address the problem (i.e. to handle the new `\@latex@error` unknown to `hyperref` which is defined by `silence`)