# Package incompatibility with hyperxmp and silence?

Tags: hyperref, packages, incompatibility, silence, hyperxmp

I was wondering how to dig into this further. I believe I saw in the silence package's changelog that it had to make some changes to be compatible with hyperref, so I wonder if I'm hitting a new bug now.

Here's a minimal example that makes my machine hang, and the order the packages are loaded in doesn't make a difference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage{hyperref,hyperxmp}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

So I was wondering what I could do about this, or who I should report the bug to: hyperxmp, or silence.

I might have got a clue from using \RequirePackage before the preamble. That gives me this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \maketitle already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.235 }
```

and if I press Return to continue, then it hangs

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Well,why do you need `silence`? THe given code compiles without it ...

Comment: @Mensch because I'm using a non-article document class that gives useless warnings (but for the sake of reproducing the bug, I mentioned article in my post). The answer below fixes the hang with article, but not my document class, so maybe I'll just find a new one.

Comment: @Mensch it's res.cls from https://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/ and it still hangs on a minimal file loading the packages and specifying title and author as below. I get bogus warnings about "Unused global options:[11pt]" being given to res.cls even though it does in fact work and change the size

Comment: **'res.cls' is a very outdated class and should not be used any longer.** Use a more modern template, for example `moderncv`, style `banking` ...

Comment: @John You're out of luck. I dug up a bit further and found out why these packages plus the `res` class (which is outdated!) will hang. The underlying reason is the same as in my answer: fragile code inside the error message. However differently from `article`, which you can simply provide a title and the problem goes away, the `res` class _always_ inserts fragile code in `\@title` (formatting stuff: font change, alignment, etc.). So it's sort of impossible to get that combination of packages working with `res.cls` without a considerable amount of change in the code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct solution is to *not* use the `silence` package. Really, don't use it. You'll thank me later :-)

However if you *insist* on that, then you need to add a `\title` and an `\author` to the code, before the `\begin{document}`, and it won't hang anymore:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage{hyperref,hyperxmp}
\title{anything} % added
\author{anyone} % added
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

This happens because `hyperxmp` tries to set pdf metadata, such as title and author. To do that, it uses LaTeX's `\@title` and `\@author` macros which hold, you guessed, the title and the author of the document. However, when no `\title` (or `\author`) is given, LaTeX's default is an error message (!) which says "No `\title` given" (or a "No `\author` given" warning). And do you know who messes up all of LaTeX's messages? Yes!
`silence` tries to be clever and hide the error messages, but it chokes on the unexpandable tokens `\title` and `\author` and hell breaks loose.

A slightly more detailed explanation is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451568/134574. The code is different, but it boils down to the same issue and solution. In your case the easy way out is to give a `\title` and an `\author`.

---

But please, don't use `silence`. Every time you are tempted to use `silence` remember that *every* error/warning message had to be written by someone so that you can find out what went wrong more easily. Loading `silence` will just make the finding out process more difficult (as you just witnessed :-).

Comment: From silence's documentation, I was under the impression that just loading it wasn't supposed to do anything and I'd need to invoke other commands to make it hide errors and warnings.

Comment: @John That's correct, to some extent. Just loading the package indeed does not hide any errors or warnings, wowever `silence`'s machinery is still installed in LaTeX's message system. This means that even though no message is being hidden, the package has already redefined LaTeX's message commands, such as user level commands like `\PackageError`, and internal LaTeX commands, such as `\@latex@error`.

Answer (score 1):

I had an older document using now deprecated packages. I just wanted to update some links in this document. Because of the new warnings about the deprecation I included `silence` with some `\WarningFilter` commands oppressing these warnings (I planned to deal with replacement later) and run, too, into endless loading. For me it turned out that moving `\hypersetup` before ´\begin{document}´ was the solution. *There is nowhere an `\author` or `\title` included here, but **the hypersetup contains `pdftitle` and `pdfauthor`!** Without the latter the endless loading will return!*

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{hyperref,hyperxmp}

%\begin{document}

\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={Test of package "silence"},
  pdfauthor={Anne O. Nymus},
  pdfcreator={pdfTeX},
  pdfcopyright={Public domain (below threshold)}
}

\begin{document}
\duckument
\end{document}
```

Make the other `begin{document}` active or comment out `pdftitle` and `pdfauthor`.

The reason why I had `\hypersetup` after document begin was, if I remember correctly, the encoding (non ASCII characters in `pdftitle`), but this doesn’t matter anymore now if everything is converted into UTF-8.

Comment: not using silence would have been safer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know this now! :-)