# Unicode in PDF metadata with latex3 and an utf8 engine

Tags: pdf, unicode, latex3

In [Unicode in PDF Metadata](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245964/unicode-in-pdf-metadata), Heiko Oberdiek proposes a way to set the PDF metadata to some unicode string while operating at the low level, without resorting to `hyperref`.  To this aim, he ends up using the `stringenc` package to do the necessary re-encoding of the string from utf-8 to utf-16be and he needs to manually add a BOM. Here is his example:

```
% UTF-8 encoded source file
\input stringenc.sty\relax

\def\MyAuthor{Erwin Schrödinger}
\edef\BOM{\string\376\string\377}
\StringEncodingConvert{\PdfAuthor}{\MyAuthor}{utf8}{utf16be}
\StringEncodingSuccessFailure{}{%
  \errmessage{Conversion from utf8 to utf16be failed for author string}%
}
\pdfinfo{/Author(\BOM\pdfescapestring{\PdfAuthor})}%
\null
\bye
```

I wonder if there is a way to do the same without having to resort to `stringenc`, but relying on the `latex3` interfaces. I have seen that there is a whole latex3 package for string encoding conversions, that is `l3str-convertpackage`.  However, I cannot find anything strightforwardly doing what I need. For instance, is there a pre-made BOM definition for PDF metadata? Should I rely on `\str_set_convert:Nnnn` to do the conversion (possibly with a `:NVnn` variant?). Is there an all-in one function doing the conversion for me? `\str_convert_pdfname:n` is certainly not what I am looking for, right?

Comment: you can do it with expl3 interfaces. `\str_set_convert:Nnnn` with utf16/string or utf16/hex as target works fine.  There are some more specialized commands in the pdfresources project we are working on, but we haven't decided yes finally about the command names and the exact interfaces.

Comment: Thanks, I have done it by mere conversion of the `stringenc` example and it works... keeping the manual addition of the BOM, which I understand is indispensable.  Because this is something that you need for setting the PDF document title, it will really be nice to have something doing the appropriate conversion in one step when it is ready.

Comment: you don't need an extra BOM, if I do `\str_set_convert:Nnnn \myauthor{Erwin~Schrödinger}{utf8}{utf16/string}
\pdfinfo{/Author(\myauthor)}` I get `/Author(\376\377\000E\000r\000w\000i\000n...` in the pdf.